# Error using LightGraphs on Atom with Julia

Tags: julia, atom-editor, lightgraphs

I am having troubles trying to use LightGraphs with Atom.

When I try `using LightGraphs`
I get

> ERROR: MethodError: no method matching
>   shouldlog(::Atom.Progress.JunoProgressLogger,
>   ::Base.CoreLogging.LogLevel, ::Module, ::Symbol, ::Symbol) The
>   applicable method may be too new: running in world age 27557, while
>   current world is 27588.

What happens there?

I use Atom, and I dont get the same problem running the same code from the terminal.

Thanks

Comment: That bug should be fixed by https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/28290

Comment: Thanks for the help, indeed it should fix it, but I don't really understand what exactly I have to do? Sorry I am new to Julia and I don't fully understand it yet.

Comment: If you are new to Julia I strongly suggest that you use the current release (v0.6.4) instead of the development version (it looks like you use v0.7-).